# Determining the method called within a lambda function

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I have a lambda function which is passed to a object and stored as a variable:

```
f = lambda x: x.method_foo()
```

I want to determine the name of method called on the variable `x` as a string. So I want

```
method_foo
```

saved as a string.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do. Can you please explain more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could access the lambda's code object with `func_code`, and access the code's local names with `co_names`.

```
>>> f = lambda x: x.method_foo
>>> f.func_code.co_names
('method_foo',)
>>> f.func_code.co_names[0]
'method_foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit "crazy", but you can use pass a [`Mock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html) to `f` and get the method that was added to the mock after calling the function:

```
>>> from mock import Mock
>>> f = lambda x: x.method_foo
>>> m = Mock()
>>> old_methods = dir(m)
>>> f(m)
<Mock name='mock.method_foo' id='4517582608'>
>>> new_methods = dir(m)
>>> next(method for method in new_methods if method not in old_methods)
'method_foo'
```

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I wanted. I have no idea how it works though

Comment: @Josh yeah, it's just an alternative "out of normal" way to accomplish the task. Kevin's way is definitely more pythonic.